# REST Service - org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property error

Tags: java, android, hibernate, rest, httprequest

I am trying to send data from my android app to my REST service so that it can be stored on a database. I have successfully done this in another app that I have worked on and when I am trying to do it with this project I am getting this error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: line_type

In my Oracle Database the field is named `"LINE_TYPE`" and is `VARCHAR2(20 BYTE).`

Here is the code in my REST service table (which I have reverse engineered from my oracle database):

```
 private String lineType;

 @Column(name="LINE_TYPE")
@Size(max = 20, message = "Line Type has a max size of 20 characters.")
public String getLineType() {
    return this.lineType;
}

public void setLineType(String lineType) {
    this.lineType = lineType;
}
```

Also in my tableCriteria I have the `getters` and `setters`:

```
 public String getLineType() {
    return lineType;
}

public void setLineType(String lineType) {
    this.lineType = lineType;
}
```

The last time I had this error it was through a spelling mistake or case sensitivity but I have double and triple checked and that is not the case here.

I have debugged the entity that the REST service is receiving in NetBeans and I can see that it is receiving the data. So why cant it be resolved?

Anyone see anything I don't?

Comment: Try changing your setter name from setLineType to only 'lineType()'

Comment: @RohanKadu thanks for the suggestion, it didn't work and produced a lot more errors

Comment: I had an issue with a library where, the object name in the database, had to be exactly the same as the java object or the mapping would just fail. Have you tried private String LINE_TYPE; ?